# This confuses in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, this

Hey friends am really stuck with `this` property in javascript.

```
Collection.prototype.onOpen = function () {

  var self = this;

  this.buffer = function() {
return this
}

  self.doQueue();
};
```

I just need to know what `this` corresponds here..Is `this` corresponds to Collection here .

Please help me ..Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks

Comment: Just looking at that code you posted, it is impossible to say what `this` will be. It completely depends on how the "onOpen" function is called.

Comment: You should read up on scoping but in your case why not console.log it if you're unsure?  It'll tell you in a jiffy..

Comment: I recommend to read the MDN documentation about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is complicated, but usually referring to its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` changes depending upon how the function was invoked;

```
Collection.prototype.onOpen(); // `this` refers to `Collection.prototype`
// vs
var c = new Collection();
c.onOpen(); // `this` refers to `c`
// vs
var o = {};
Collection.prototype.onOpen.call(o); // `this` refers to `o`
// vs
var foo = Collection.prototype.onOpen;
foo(); // `this` could be `window` or undefined
```

---

Perhaps a some examples will aid you in your understanding of how `this` changes

```
// set up
var o = {};        // So we have an empty Object called `o`
function foo() {   // and a function called `foo` which lets
    return this;   // us see the value of `this` by returning
}                  // it
o.bar = foo;       // and set `bar` of `o` to be `foo`, too

// example 1
foo(); // `window` if in global scope (see example 4 for other scopes)
// example 2
o.bar(); // `o`
// example 3
foo.call(o);  // `o`, same as `o.bar.call(o);`
foo.apply(o); // `o`, same as `o.bar.apply(o);`

// example 4, complex
(function () {    // IIFE creates a new scope
    "use strict"; // and let's have it in in strict mode
    function baz() {
        return this;
    }
    return baz();
}()); // = `this` from `baz` = undefined

// example 5, inheritance
function Fizz() {
}
Fizz.prototype.buzz = foo;
var fizz = new Fizz();
fizz.buzz(); // `fizz`
```

Comment: So you says this refers to Collection here ..?right ?

Comment: @user3517846 you've not shown us how you're invoking it

Comment: @user3517846 No. **Read** the answer. The **entire** answer.

Comment: Actually is the use of "this" necessary in javascript ?

Comment: @user3517846 Yes. `this` is a very important keyword in JavaScript, although it differs from other languages like Java.

Comment: In this code i have given   this.buffer = false;  Is this keywords corresponds to the function onOpen ?

Comment: @user3517846 how is the function invoked?

Comment: suppose if i call onOpen.buffer(this) ..Then this corresponds to OnOpen right ?

Comment: @user3517846 I've edited in some examples you can try, maybe they will help you :)

Comment: I have understood .but what will this correspond if i call onOpen.buffer(this) ?

Comment: is it possible ??..then what will this correspond if i call onOpen.buffer(this) ?

Comment: @user3517846 I don't see any function called `buffer`, so I can't tell you, why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: @PaulS. now see it ..now i can call onOpen.buffer(this) ? ..so what will be the corresponding this there ..is it onOpen..

Comment: ???..Am i right ..Is this correspond onOpen ?